# View All Items submitted by a Single User in Yootheme Zoo

Tags: joomla-3.x, zoo

I am creating a multi-vendor shopping site with Zoo and Zoolanders Zoocart extension.

What is left is creating a link that will display all items posted by a single user.

I know Zoo does not have that by default.. Please can someone can help me do that??

Answer (score 1):

Zoolanders have another plugin call Zooaccess and Module call Zoofilter.

With this tools you gona success.

https://www.zoolanders.com/extensions/zooaccess

https://www.zoolanders.com/extensions/zoofilter

I hope this helps.